# Import Swift framework (CocoaPod) into Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, bridging-header

I would like to use `SevenSwitch` framework (swift framework) in Objective-C project. I'm using cocoapods. The project name is ChillN, and I have a file named : `ChillN-Swift.h` (for bridging Swift file).

Now I would like to import and use SevenSwitch in Objective-C Class.

Here is what I've done :

myClass.h:

```
#import "ChillN-Swift.h"
@class SevenSwitch;
@interface myClass : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet SevenSwitch *mySwitch;
```

myClass.m:

```
[self.mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.mySwitch.on = YES;
```

But here, `self.mySwitch` isn't recognized. How can I make that ?

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ChillN' do
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 2.0.5'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'SevenSwitch', '~> 2.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'
pod 'HSDatePickerViewController', '~> 1.0'
end

target 'ChillNTests' do

end
```

Here is my ChillN-Swift.h:

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81)
#pragma clang diagnostic push

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wauto-import"
#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<uchar.h>)
# include <uchar.h>
#elif !defined(__cplusplus) || __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
#endif

typedef struct _NSZone NSZone;

#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif

#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(swift_name)
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X) __attribute__((swift_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted) 
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM)
# define SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
#endif
typedef float swift_float2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef float swift_float3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef float swift_float4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef double swift_double2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef double swift_double3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef double swift_double4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef int swift_int2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef int swift_int3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef int swift_int4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

And I have two files : "ChillN-Bridging-Header.h" in supporting files and one in project.

ChillN-Bridging-Header.h:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//
```

Comment: What does your bridging header look like?

Comment: Is your SevenSwitch is derived from NSObject? If not it can not be used and will never appear in your bridging ChillN-Swift.h.

Comment: @Shripada thanks man for reply, my "ChillN-Bridging-Header.h" are in ChillN > Supporting files with the file SevenSwitch.h. Now it's working. But if I want to use the SevenSwitch.h from Pods (Pods > Pods > SevenSwitch > SevenSwitch.h) it doesn't work. Maybe I have to add some path in settings ?